# quicksort code in Python

Tags: python, quicksort

I am trying to code quicksort in Python but wasn't able to correct the errors? How do I fix all these errors? Is there anything wrong with the logic?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  line 35, in module  
  line 5, in quicksort  
  line 3, in quicksort  
  line 30, in partition  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
def quicksort(a, beg, end):
   if beg < end:
     split = partition(a, beg, end)
     quicksort(a, beg, split-1)
     quicksort(a, split+1, end)

def partition(a, beg, end):
    left = beg
    right = end
    pivot = left
    done = True
    while done:
        while a[pivot] <= a[right] and pivot != right:
            right = right - 1
        if pivot == right:
           done = False
        elif a[pivot] > a[right] :
           temp = a[right]
           a[right] = a[pivot]
           a[pivot] = a[temp]
           pivot = right 

        while a[pivot] >= a[left] and pivot != left:
            left = left + 1
        if pivot == left:
            done = False
        elif a[pivot] < a[left] :
           temp = a[left]
           a[left] = a[pivot]
           a[pivot] = a[temp]
           pivot = left
    return pivot             

a = [4, 5, 7, 3, 6, 22, 45, 82]
quicksort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
print(a)
```

Comment: add the full traceback to your question.  It will show you where your code is failing

Comment: did you figure it out? if not, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    elif a[pivot] > a[right] :
       temp = a[right]
       a[right] = a[pivot]
       a[pivot] = a[temp]
       pivot = right
```

Notice you set `a[pivot]` to `a[temp]`.  You need to set it to `temp`.

and here:

```
   elif a[pivot] < a[left] :
       temp = a[left]
       a[left] = a[pivot]
       # a[pivot] = a[temp]
       a[pivot] = temp
       pivot = left
```

Even better, use tuple unpacking -- you don't need temp:

```
    elif a[pivot] > a[right] :
       a[pivot], a[right] = a[right], a[pivot]
       """
       temp = a[right]
       a[right] = a[pivot]
       a[pivot] = a[temp]
       """
```

Comment: so that's where i was getting the out of the index list error .thanks mr joel .it's working now

Comment: I know its working.  I tested it.  You can check my answer if it solved your problem @KritiSahu